# Is ResourceBundleControlProvider virtually deprecated in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, deprecated, resourcebundle

The official [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/ResourceBundleControlProvider.html) for `ResourceBundleControlProvider` says:

> Provider implementations must be packaged using the [Java Extension Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/index.html) as installed extensions. ...
>
> **Since: 1.8**

However, when you click on the mentioned [Java Extension Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/index.html) link, it says:

> This feature **has been deprecated** and will be removed in a future release.

Does this mean that the `ResourceBundleControlProvider` interface was introduced to Java 1.8 as already deprecated? Shall we start using it at all? Why is it there?

It looks like it has been introduced to Java 8 by mistake, as [Deprecate ResourceBundleControlProvider for removal](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8171189) Open JDK bug suggests:

> This interface was introduced in JDK 8 (JDK-6380549) for a convenient way to replace the default Control with the provided one, using the Java Extension Mechanism, which is now obsolete in JDK 9. The original requestor of this feature confirms that they haven't used this API. It turned out that to our knowledge, there seem to be no users of this interface. Adding `@Deprecated` tag with `forRemoval=true` in JDK 9, and removing the interface in JDK 10 may be appropriate.

The interface looks like a stillborn feature, it's way of usage is so weird and impractical.

Answer (score 1):

It really looks like the feature will be deprecated in JDK 9, at least if the code from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/rev/760e51207cb0 will be part of the Java 9 release:

```
* @deprecated There is no longer any mechanism to install a custom
* {@code ResourceBundleControlProvider} implementation defined
* by the platform class loader or its ancestor. The recommended
* way to use a custom {@code Control} implementation to load resource bundle
* is to use {@link java.util.ResourceBundle#getBundle(String, Control)}
* or other factory methods that take custom {@link java.util.ResourceBundle.Control}.
*/
@Deprecated(since="9", forRemoval=true)
public interface ResourceBundleControlProvider {
```

Answer (score 0):

ResourceBundleControlProvider was proposed to be deprecated but it was re-examined via JDK-8172365 [1] to find a better migration path for code using this API. It is no longer deprecated. You'll see this if you download a newer build.

[1] https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172365

Comment: Well, but the *extension mechanism* is deprecated, and it *must* be used as the doc states...